# How to interop with polymorphic void pointers?

Tags: c#

I have a C API that (simplified) looks like this:

```c
int write(uint8_t type, void* ptr, uint32_t count);
int read(uint8_t type, void* ptr, uint32_t capacity, uint32_t *count);
```

It allows me to read and write objects of various types which are all well-defined both in C and on C# (i.e., I have an `enum` type enumerating them, and each enum variant has a related `struct` per language).

I now want to interop with this library from C# with the least amount of code to reduce my maintenance burden.

Originally I was attempting to define:

```cs
[DllImport(NativeLib, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "write")]
public static extern Error Write<T>(byte type, [In] T[] data, uint count);

[DllImport(NativeLib, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "read")]
public static extern Error Read<T>(byte type, [Out] T[] data, IntPtr capacity, out uint count);
```

Which, however, gave me compilation errors:

```
error CS7042: The DllImport attribute cannot be applied to a method that is generic or contained in a generic type.
```

What is the best alternative to do what I intended? I know some people recommended to overload the method with various types, but then:

- I would possibly have ~20 methods instead of 2, and
- I'd still have to provide a (now useless) `type` parameter to an already typed method.

Comment: When it comes to interop having 20 overloads is really really small problem.

Comment: *"Because unmanaged platforms outside the .NET Framework do not recognize generic types, you cannot interoperate with them using generic types."* - [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/misc/bc31526).

Comment: You may utilize [T4 templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/walkthrough-generating-code-by-using-text-templates) to generate class containing overloads for you.

Comment: You don't actually need 20 methods. Two generic methods that *call* the non-generic P/Invoke methods would do. Many unmanaged functions are much more palatable with a little wrapping; these are no different. (Solving the problem of marshaling your types through `void*` is a separate one and admits other solutions than the default marshaler, such as `unsafe` / `fixed` / `Buffer.BlockCopy` -- if you are on .NET Core these things get more convenient with `unmanaged `constraints and the `Unsafe` helper type.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert that sounds like what I am looking for. Would you have a snippet (and maybe a proposal for a better C# interop signature) that shows how in a case like this that would best work?

Comment: What version(s) of .NET/C# are you targeting? This kind of low level bit banging really did get more convenient with .NET Core, but even on Framework the newer versions of C# have some nifty things. For (say) .NET 2.0 you'd be looking at much less attractive code (though `Marshal.Copy` helps).

Comment: Unfortunately Unity 2018+, which is either Mono / "3.5" or  ".NET 4.x" ... and in a later version `.NET Standard 2.0`, according to the Editor. We'd probably want to support 3.5, but I think 4.x as a minium could work as well if necessary.

Comment: Unfortunately no `unmanaged` constraint then -- with that code like `T[] x; unsafe { fixed (void* p = x) { write(type, p, p.Length); } }` starts to work (with a constrained `T`). Without that declaring the parameters as `IntPtr` instead and using `Marshal` is probably your best bet (`Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement`, `Marshal.PtrToStructure`). Getting that to work is more fiddly though. I lack the time for a full answer (including proper testing, which is vital).